# NetLogo addition of nominal values giving unusual results

Tags: netlogo

When a variable is being incremented by very small value (say 0.01), it is not giving proper (precise) results as expected.

Looking for suggestions(if any) to deal with the same.

```
globals[p]
to go
set p 0
while[p <= 1]
[
    print p
    set p p + 0.01

]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First read this:
http://floating-point-gui.de/

Then to subdivide an interval into `n` pieces, do this:

```
to-report subdivide [#xmin #xmax #n]
  let ps n-values (#n + 1) [? / #n]
  report map [#xmin + ? * (#xmax - #xmin)] ps
end
```